# App hangs to show error “SQLiteConnectionPool: The connection pool for database '+app_dbV8' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 2 (main)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite

**Scenario:** App Scans a QR code using Zxing library. When scanning usecase is initiated, app’s **main activity** launches **activity A** which initializes the UI , checks the basic permissions (like camera access,) , it then launches **activity B** for scanning the image. Scanning is done two ways, one is through camera and another is by picking an image from gallery.

**What works:** Scanning through camera and scanning valid QR code files from the gallery works

**Issue:** After scanning an invalid QR code from gallery. On pressing back button on the toolbar of **activity A**, app hangs. On the run window, this message is displayed “SQLiteConnectionPool: The connection pool for database '+appname_dbV8' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 2 (main) with flags 0x5 for 16.006 seconds

**Activity A:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
    Toolbar toolbar = getActionBarToolbar();
    toolbar.setTitle("Scan");
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_up);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            navigateUpToFromChild(ActivityA.this,
                    Intent.makeMainActivity(new ComponentName(ActivityA.this,
                            mymainactivity.class)));
        }
    });

    setEventListeners();
        
}

private void initiateScan () {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setCaptureActivity(ActivityB.class);
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}

private void setEventListeners () {

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scan cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            String decoderesult = "";
            try {
                decoderesult = URLDecoder.decode(result.getContents(), "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                //Log error message
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException i) {
//log error message
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unsupported scan Code!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }

            if (decoderresult is a valid scan code) {

        //parse and handle the scan code
                          
            } else { //handle invalid QR code
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid QR Code!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    } else

    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

**Activity B:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Scan");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    barcodeScannerView = (DecoratedBarcodeView) findViewById(R.id.zxing_barcode_scanner);
    barcodeScannerView.setTorchListener(this);



    switchFlashlightButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.switch_flashlight);

    // if the device does not have flashlight in its camera,
    // then remove the switch flashlight button...
    if (!hasFlash()) {
        switchFlashlightButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    capture = new CaptureManager(this, barcodeScannerView);
    capture.initializeFromIntent(getIntent(), savedInstanceState);
    capture.decode();
}

//XML file has the corresponding onclick for gallery_browse 
public void gallery_browse(View view){
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
}
 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
            Log.e("TAG", "The uri is null, probably the user cancelled the image selection process using the back button.");
            return;
        }
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            if (bitmap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not a valid QR code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            int width = bitmap.getWidth(), height = bitmap.getHeight();
            int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
            bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = null;
            RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(width, height, pixels);
            BinaryBitmap bBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
            MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
            String data = "";
            Result result;
            Hashtable<DecodeHintType, String> hints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, String>();
            hints.put(DecodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");
            try {
                result = reader.decode(bBitmap, hints);
                resultdata = result.getText();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException i) {
                
            } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                ULog.e("Not found exception in class " + getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
                RemoteLogger.b(e.getMessage());
            }

            if (resultdata is valid) {

        //  Parse and process the data
                
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Seems to be an Invalid QR Code. Try another QR code!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "can not open file" + uri.toString(), e);
        }
    }
    else{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. In the code which I have provided here, in activity B, after decode, in Notfoundexception block there was a remote logger code which was causing the app to hang and later crash.

This was the part of code that was causing the issue:

```
 ULog.e("Not found exception in class " + getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
 RemoteLogger.b(e.getMessage());
```